# Basic smtp commands to test inherited project?

Tags: java, smtp, smtpclient, smtp-auth

I have inherited a java application (.war) that is essentially an smtp client.  I can start it up using mvn:jetty run and then telnet successfully to a port that the application opens 8024.

$ telnet localhost 8024
>

However, how can I issue a basic smtp command to test against?  I'm still digging though the code but need to know some basic commands to issue for starters and see if it's at least working or responding to basic smtp commands.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need any smtp commands. Check out this library: [GreenMail](http://www.icegreen.com/greenmail/). You can use it for testing purposes and it comes with a server and a client so you can test a client with the server version and server with the client one. Check out the [examples](http://www.icegreen.com/greenmail/examples.html) section. It is really straight forward and very rewarding. It should provide anything you need for your task.